# Pry session timing out because of Puma worker timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, pry

Whenever I hit a `binding.pry` while running an app locally, I enter the pry session as normal, but after about a minute, I see something like this in my server output.

`[54438] ! Terminating timed out worker: 54455`

Then the server seems to run in a loop for a second or two (re-running queries that lead to the pry session) and I return to a new pry session from the same `binding.pry`, except in this new pry session whenever I type I can't see anything I'm typing. The only way to fix this problem is to quit the server and restart.

I've tried inserting the following line in my `config/puma.rb` file but it doesn't seem to make any difference. 

`worker_timeout 900 if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "development"`

The only thing that works is setting the number of puma workers I have to 0 in my .env file. E.g

`PUMA_WORKERS=0`

Is there any way around this issue that doesn't involve just eliminating all puma workers?

Comment: What command are you using to start your Puma server?

Comment: @garythegoat just using `rails s` but I've also tried `puma -C config/puma.rb` and I doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I think your condition is wrong. Try removing it or changing it to `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development"`

Comment: In rails you can also do `Rails.env.development?`

Comment: @Slicedpan it seems you were right. For some reason a this point RACK_ENV is not yet set but RAILS_ENV is set (by my .env file).

Comment: Quick note - 5 years on! - puma doesn't have access to `Rails.env` during boot time, so checking ENV["RAILS_ENV"] is required

Answer (score 0):

Puma config file is read upon Puma initialization, the application is not loaded yet, that's why `Rails.env.development?` does not work, neither using `RACK_ENV`, because you are not in the scope of a request.

If you want to change the worker_timeout only for development you should do something like:

```
worker_timeout 900 unless ENV.key?('RAILS_ENV') && ENV['RAILS_ENV'] != 'development'
```

This means, set the timeout to 900 when there is not a RAILS_ENV set or whenever it is set to `development`.